# Obtaining canonical url using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

I'm building a website internally and the page has a [canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_meta_tag) URL set in the `<head>` that specifies the page's URL externally.

Is there any way to use JavaScript to obtain the canonical URL?

Comment: Kind sir, please provide an HTML example so we may better help you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://www.example.com/" rel="canonical" />
        <title>Canonical</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var canonical = "";
                var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
                for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i ++) {
                    if (links[i].getAttribute("rel") === "canonical") {
                        canonical = links[i].getAttribute("href")
                    }
                }
                alert(canonical);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Canonical</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 70):

Well nowadays you can simply use:

```
document.querySelector("link[rel='canonical']").getAttribute("href");
```

The above answear will give you true value of href attribute. So it will show you href like  `/query.html` if you don't have full URL.

But `.href` method will give you always full URL with domain like `http://example.com/query.html`:

```
document.querySelector("link[rel='canonical']").href;
```

Comment: Yeah. But adding 90kB of jquery to get something that simple is not a good option imvho :-)

Comment: Agree, but if one decides to use jQuery anyway it comes handy for those selectors as well.

Comment: I've updated answer with additional explanation how `.href` method is different.

Answer (score 22):

jquery version;

```
$("link[rel='canonical']").attr("href")
```